# doing project but for some reason cycle doesn't work

Tags: c#, forms, cycle

i'm drawing rectangles in line, and every turn it's supposed to delete one rectangles every turn, until i wont be less than 1, but for some reason it's only deleting one rectangle and thats it, what am i doing wrong?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int h = 0;
        int w = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gr = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            {
                
                    for (i = 5; i > 1; i--)
                    {
                        
                            gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, 70 + y, 60 + h, 60 + w);
                            x += 70;                    
                    }
                    x = 0;
                    y += 70;
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD8he.png)

Comment: which line  delete one rectangles ?

Comment: for (i = 5; i > 1; i--) is supposed to draw one less rectangle but this not happens

Comment: looked picture it's draw 4 times rect , so what wrong in here ?

Comment: you don't want to draw 4 times ?

Comment: wdym? isnt for (i = 5; i > 1; i--) supposed to minus every time until i is 1? or im getting it wrong?

Comment: The loop you have now is always going to iterate the same number of times because it is initialized with a constant, `5`. Maybe you want to use another variable that initially holds `5` to initialize `i` in the loop and then decrement that variable once per tick.

Comment: condition is ( i > 1 ) , so it running  i = 5 , 4 , 3 , 2  , not running i = 1

Comment: and why you don't just write like this ? `for(int i = 0; i < 5 ;i++)`

Comment: @TimChang maybe they want to render a count down on the rectangles later

Comment: Instead of doing all this painting blah blah, why don't you just put 5 labels with a border, on your form, sized and placed where you want, and then remove them one by one each time the timer ticks. Right now, as you've got it, the code will just draw another row of 4 rectangles every time the timer ticks, forever; it's hard to tell what you're trying to implement becuase this is quite at odds with what you say you're trying to do

Comment: @TimChang i need that every tick there was one less rectangle (first tick 5, second - 4, third - 3 and etc)

Comment: @CaiusJard my teach want it with loop

Comment: you can do it without for loop first , just copy and paste code  , and make sure what you thing is worked . if it's worked paste the code on this post  , we can help you.

Comment: `gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 70 , 70 + y, 60 + h, 60 + w);`
`gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 140 , 70 + y, 60 + h, 60 + w);`
`gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 210 , 70 + y, 60 + h, 60 + w);` ... maybe like that , I don't know